# Data not passing from form to controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, controller

I'd like to pass data from a form to my controller and from there I want to save them into my database, but when I try to save the data in the controller the array is empty.

**VIEW PAGE**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?    >index.php/users/save_record">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Age:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" id="age">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Sex:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sex" id="sex">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Phone Number:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phno" id="phno">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function save_record()
    {   
        if ($this->input->post('submit')==true) 
        {
        $udata['name']=$this->input->post['name'];
        $udata['age']=$this->input->post['age'];
        $udata['sex']=$this->input->post['sex'];
        $udata['phno']=$this->input->post['phno'];
        //$this->Users_model->save_user($udata);    
        var_dump($udata);
        }   
    }
```

**RESULT**

```
array(4) { ["name"]=> NULL ["age"]=> NULL ["sex"]=> NULL ["phno"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: create array like this $data = array("name"=>$this->input->post('age'),"name"=>$this->input->post('age'));

Comment: @Yaseen the method of pushing to an array used in the example above is fine. the usage of the $this->input->post['phno'] is wrong, should be $this->input->post('phno');

Comment: thanx a lot ....code you have written is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. Try this.

```
if ($this->input->post('submit') == true) {
    $udata['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
    $udata['age'] = $this->input->post('age');
    $udata['sex'] = $this->input->post('sex');
    $udata['phno'] = $this->input->post('phno');
    //$this->Users_model->save_user($udata);    
    var_dump($udata);
}
```